# How to define relation in laravel 5.3 eloquent model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, laravel-5.3

I have tables in my database schema as follows,

[image]

Is it pivot table?

How can I define relationship in eloquent model?

```
    class Role extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RolePermission', 'permissions_id');
    }

}
```

Is this correct way to define relationship? Please help me to understand.

and

```
    class RolePermission extends Model {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role', 'roles_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to name your table `permission_role` to follow the design pragma.

#### Role Schema

```
Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
   
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Permission schema

```
Schema::create('permissions', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then you just need the `permission_role` table:

#### Permission_Role schema

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Then you just set up your models like this:

```
class Role {
    public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Permission::class);
    }
}
```

Then of course your permission class

```
class Permission {
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Role::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's many-to-many why is one `hasMany` and the other `belongsToMany`?  It kind of implies that the many-to-many relationship is different depending on the side you see it from.

Comment: [laracasts/generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) makes creating pivot tables easier.

Answer (score 0):

its a many to many relationship bond together by a pivot table Permission_Role. there for each table belongsToMany not hasOne or hasMany

```
class Role {
    public function permissions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Permission::class);
    }
}

class Permission {
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Role::class);
    }
}
```